# reading and formatting csv data using explode and arrays in php

Tags: php

**The Objective**

To read the csv file, and separate each line into an array. The first line (field names) displayed once, and then loop through the remaining data.

I have this function to open and explode the csv file

```
$myFile = "csv.csv";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
$csv = explode(",", $theData);
```

This is the CSV file in question

```
id,sub,type,regprice,natprice
1,4,Team,40,75
2,4,Individual,15,35
3,4,Stunt Group,50,150
4,4,Coed Partner Stunt,50,150
```

What i need to know how to do, is load the first line into an array separately, then loop through the remaining arrays in the following manner.

```
Array[0][0] - Array[0][1] - Array[0][2] - Array[0][3] - Array[0][4]
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Array[1][0] - Array[1][1] - Array[1][2] - Array[1][3] - Array[1][4]
Array[2][0] - Array[2][1] - Array[2][2] - Array[2][3] - Array[2][4]
Array[3][0] - Array[3][1] - Array[3][2] - Array[3][3] - Array[3][4]
Array[4][0] - Array[4][1] - Array[4][2] - Array[4][3] - Array[4][4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work

I added a / at the end of the CSV lines.

```
$myFile = "csv.csv";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);
$csvpre = explode("/", $theData);
$i = 1;
    foreach ( $csvpre AS $key => $value){
        $info = explode(",", $value);    
            if($i == "1"){
                echo "$info[0] - $info[1] - $info[2] - $info[3] - $info[4]<br>";
                $i++;
                } else {
                echo "<span style=\"color:#ff0000;\">$info[0] - $info[1] - $info[2] - $info[3] - $info[4]</span><br>";
            }       
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

[`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) will probably do all this for you.

Comment: @eyze fgetcsv() takes a resource handle from fopen(). file() is a solid alternative if you REALLY need to explode the csv columns yourself as it will return an array strings representing each line.

Comment: you can mix file() with str_getcsv() :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
  $rowStr = implode(' - ',$row)."\n";
  print($rowStr);
  if ($i == 0) {
    print(str_repeat('-',strlen($rowStr))."\n");
  }
}
```

Edit: fixed syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$myFile = "csv.csv";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$headers = fgetcsv($fh);
$data = array();
while (! feof($fh))
{
    $row = fgetcsv($fh);
    if (!empty($row))
    {
        $obj = new stdClass;
        foreach ($row as $i => $value)
        {
            $key = $headers[$i];
            $obj->$key = $value;
        }
        $data[] = $obj;
    }
}
fclose($fh);
print_r($data);
?>
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [sub] => 4
            [type] => Team
            [regprice] => 40
            [natprice] => 75
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [sub] => 4
            [type] => Individual
            [regprice] => 15
            [natprice] => 35
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [sub] => 4
            [type] => Stunt Group
            [regprice] => 50
            [natprice] => 150
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [sub] => 4
            [type] => Coed Partner Stunt
            [regprice] => 50
            [natprice] => 150
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_array=file('csv.csv');
$lines=count($file_array);

$first_line=explode(',',$file_array[0]);
$fl_text=implode(' - ',$first_line);    
echo $fl_text.'<br>';

for($i=1;$i<$lines;$i++)
   {
   $line_text=str_replace(',',' - ',$file_array[$i]);
   echo '<span style="color:#ff0000;">'.$line_text.'</span><br>';
   }
```

This includes a couple of ways to print out the lines without needing to explode each one. You can replace the ',' with a space using str_replace, or you can explode and then implode. Probably str_replace is more efficient.

Also, the file() command reads each line of a file into values in an array.